# Any way to do document.createElement("xsl:variable")

Tags: javascript, dom

It is possible to use `document.createElement("select")` to make a new select element `<select></select>`

Is there any was to do the same with `document.createElement("xsl:variable")` to create a `<xsl:variable></xsl:variable>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use [`document.createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElementNS).